# question about area of cubes

Tags: geometry

A rectangular block has dimensions 24cm by 9cm by 7cm. It is cut into childrens bricks. Each brick has a cube side 3 cm. Find the largest number of bricks that can be cut from the block? ( Arent u supposed to find the area of the rectangular block and divide it by the area of the brick?)

Comment: Not necessarily. The problem is that 3 doesn't go into 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\ 24/3 * 9/3 * 6/3 = 48$$
$$\ 24 * 9 * 6 / 3^3 = 48$$
You first need to round each dimension down to a multiple of three, then you can divide each dimension by three and you'll have the amount of bricks.  You could also divide the volume of the rectangular box after rounding $(24*9*6)$ by the volume of a children's brick $(3^3)$ to get the answer.